# SQL save different versions of same product in table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a products table in postgres that stores all the data I need. What I need to work out the best way to do:

Each product has a different status on the way to completion - machined, painted, assembled, etc. For each status there is a letter that changes in the product id.

What would the most efficient way of saving the data? For each status of the product should there be 'another product' in the table? Or would doing join tables somewhere work?

Example:

```
111a1 for machined
111b1 for painted
```

Yet these are the same end product, just at different stages ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to be efficient: storage, ingestion, queries, maintainability...

Joins would work - you can join on some substring of the product id, so you need not have separate products for every stage of production.

But maintainability of your code is really important. Businesses change - perhaps to include sub-assemblies.

You might want to re-think this scheme of altering the product id to show the status.  Product ID and work flow state are orthogonal concepts.  So you probably want to have them in separate fields.  You'll probably write far less code that way.  The alternative will be becoming really well acquainted with `substr()` (depending on your SQL dialect), and all sorts of duplications elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the way it has been done on paper as ive got the job of getting a system together to replace paper was there was a different product id for each stage albeit 1 letter. From what i understand your saying is to look at it with the product  id in 1 column with a status in another?what about the whole pk issue as that would of been my primary choice...

Comment: You can have a Composite Primary Key, with the part number and status being the two parts of the key.  Do you have different workflows for different parts?  If the workflows are the same (i.e. the manufacturing processes the part goes through), then there's a strong argument for factoring this out - keeping the status separate to the part.  Will your system be required to flag strange behaviour where the processes are not followed in sequence?  Having the logic for this associated with the workflow will be easier to set up.

Comment: The parts will have different workflows as some will be painted others will be anodised . We may stock a part that gets machined then wait a while till it goes and gets painted. As we will need to monitor stock for each process then they would have to have individual parts in the table?